# Extracting Table data from Raster created by iterated visibility test

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-table, visibility

I would like to run a visibility test using the observer function on each of 500 random points in a region, and end up, ultimately with a table showing the visible area results (count cell for each value of 1 from each table). First I have not successfully iterated the visibility test as there are more than 16 points. I want each point to be extracted from the feature layer, its visibility analyzed and out-putted to a table with the value and count. How can I get model builder to look now at the attribute tables of each raster, and extract only the row with "value =1"? 
[image]

Comment: Your problem is with the iterator, namely it is the wrong one. Currently you are trying to compute visibality to all 500 points at once, thus the tool is telling you it can only process 16. Switch your iterator to [Iterate Row Selection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004000000010000000.htm)

Comment: Thanks @polyGeo but this appears not to solve the problem either (getting the same error visible in the original screenshot). Is there a specific parameter I need to set before Row Selection will work do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your screen shot I cannot see any immediate problem with the general workflow of it.

I would imagine (based upon the reported error message) that you have not set up the iterator correctly. Did you set the group by field? If not, the iterator would serve out the entire point dataset. You need to set the group by field to a field that will uniquely identify each point, this would be an ID field like the FID or OBJECTID field.